# How to save a fig with a title above?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I created two graphs with a title for each ("petit titre") and a large title for both of them ("GRAND TITRE"). To nicely display the graph on my jupyter notebook, I anchored them as follow:

```
ax.set_title('petit titre A', pad=25, loc='left')
```

and

```
fig.suptitle("GRAND TITRE", y=1.10)
```

Then, jupyter displays this following graph:
[image]

Now, and here is my trouble, I would like to save it:

```
fig.savefig(os.path.join(path_img, 'Fig1.png'), dpi=600)
fig.savefig(os.path.join(path_img, 'Fig1.pdf'))
```

However, what I finaly get is this:

[image]

I do understand that, cause of my title anchored with an y-value = 1.1, I'm above the fig. But, it seems to me the only way to nicely organise my graph. How can I do to ask a plot taking into account the "grand titre" ? Idem if I have a legend box?

In advance, thanks for your help.
Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)`  when creating the figure and *not* anchoring the `subtitle` (i.e. just `fig.suptitle("GRAND TITRE")`).  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html#suptitle

Or, if you really want to anchor outside the figure, try `fig.savefig(os.path.join(path_img, 'Fig1.png'), dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')`  (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. I used "bbox_inches='tight'"